# Lift-mongo-record: Empty JsonObjectField in mongo collection

Tags: json, scala, mongodb, playframework, lift

I'm trying to save a record with JsonObjectField (using lift-mongo-
record in Play framework) but it is empty in database collection.
That's my code:

Define classes:

```
class Wish extends MongoRecord[Wish] with MongoId[Wish] {
  def meta = Wish
  object body extends StringField(this, 1024)
  object tags extends MongoListField[Wish, String](this)
  object form extends JsonObjectField[Wish, Criterion](this, Criterion) {
    def defaultValue = null.asInstanceOf[Criterion]
  }
}
object Wish extends Wish with MongoMetaRecord[Wish] {
  override def collectionName = "wishes"
}

case class Criterion (key: String, value: String) extends JsonObject[Criterion] {
  def meta = Criterion
}
object Criterion extends JsonObjectMeta[Criterion]
```

I try to save record in that way:

```
Wish.createRecord.body("body").tags(List("tags", "test")).form(new Criterion("From", "Arbat")).save
```

And in mongodb collection I have smth like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4dfb6f45e4b0ad4484d3e8c6"), "body" : "body", "tags" : [ "tags", "test" ], "form" : { } }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine.  Maybe try using MongoCaseClassField like:

```
object form extends MongoCaseClassField[Wish, Criterion](this)

case class Criterion (key: String, value: String){}

//btw you can leave out the "new" for case classes - it calls 
//the automatically generated apply method
Wish.createRecord.body("body").tags(List("tags", "test"))
            .form(Criterion("From","Arbat")).save
```

Here's an example for MongoCaseClassListField:

```
object form extends MongoCaseClassListField[Wish, Criterion](this)

Wish.createRecord.body("body").tags(List("tags","test"))
       .form(List(Criterion("key1","val1"), Criterion("key2", "val2"))
       .save
```

Comment: thanks. perhaps the problem is in my environment. I didn't know that there is this field in lift-mongo-record and may be this works. Can i save list of MongoCaseClassField? because actuaslly i need a list of key,value pairs. And (the question is old) i already use BsonRecordListField. Perhaps i had to say this in comment when i accepted this decision

Comment: Hi, yes you can use MongoCaseClassListField :) Hope that helps!